# how to add elements and objects to arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects with one of key/value pairs being another array.  The array of objects is 'sections' and the key/value array is 'data'.  I need to add elements to the 'data' array and new objects to the 'sections' array.

It's taken me a while but the code below seems to work.  Could someone comment if this is the 'right' way to do this or suggest an alternative approach?

In the code comments I show how to use spread notation to add elements to the 'data' array. We can also use the spread notation for sections:

```
  this.setState({...this.state,sections: 
  [...newSections,{title:this.state.key,data:this.state.input.split(',')}] })
```

```js
this.state={
  show: false,
  addDisplay:true,
  key:'',
  sections: [
    {
      title:'primary', 
      data:[]
    },
  ]
}

update = () => 
{
  console.log('UPDATESTART',this.state)
  for(var i = 0; i< this.state.input.length; i++)
  {
  //if someone enters an array with no key do nothing
    if(this.state.input[i] === ',' && this.state.key==='')
    {
      return
    }
  }


  var newSections=[];

  if(this.state.key==='')
  {
    newSections=[...this.state.sections]
    newSections[0].data.push(this.state.input) 
    // or newSections[0].data=[...newSections[0].data,this.state.input]
    this.setState({...this.state,sections: newSections })
  }
  else
  {
    newSections=[...this.state.sections]
    console.log('AA',newSections)
    newSections.push({title:this.state.key,data:this.state.input.split(',')})
    this.setState({...this.state,sections: newSections })
  }

  this.setState({input:'',key:'',show:false},function(){
  console.log('UPDATEEND',this.state)
})
```

Comment: `this.state.sections['newKey'] = {newObj}`

Comment: *Could someone comment if this is the 'right' way to do this or suggest an alternative approach?* more suitable for : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This looks like react component. Can you post the entire component to give us a better idea of what's going on

Comment: the entire component would just distract.  The issue is really just about how to address and change objects, arrays and nested arrays